# How do I test that static assert does indeed assert for "false"?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, static-assert

Suppose I have a custom static assert implementation (because I need to target a compiler that doesn't have `static_assert` built in). I want to craft a test that checks that

```
MY_STATIC_ASSERT(false);
```

indeed asserts. If I just write such code - it will not compile (and so not run). I'd rather have some piece of code that compiles fine when the code above fails and fails to compile when the code above does compile.

Is that possible? Can I have a compile-time (or at least a runtime) check that my static assert indeed asserts for "false"?

Comment: ahh, the old question - who tests the testmen!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can have a "compile-time" check - as long as you're compiling something else entirely:

```
// test_my_static_assert.cpp

#include "my_static_assert.h"

int main() {
    MY_STATIC_ASSERT(false);
}

// compile.sh
if g++ test_my_static_assert.cpp; then
    echo "MY_STATIC_ASSERT failed! Compile succeeded!"
fi
```

Or something. But it'd have to be in a separate program entirely.

Comment: I guess I can have this as a "build step" in Visual Studio or an equivalent in other build system.